# How do I organize imports with `tsserver` using Neovim LSP?

Tags: neovim, lsp, filetype-typescript

I'm using Neovim 0.9 and [lsp-zero](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim) to edit Typescript files. `tsserver` has an [organize imports feature](https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server#organize-imports). How do I map that back through LSP to a user-defined key? Basically, I'd like to add a new keybinding as shown in the [lsp-zero "create keybindings" docs](https://github.com/VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim/blob/v1.x/doc/md/lsp.md#create-new-keybindings), but I don't know how to access the `tsserver`-specific functionality from `vim.lsp.whatever`:

```
lsp.on_attach(function(client, bufnr)
  local opts = {buffer = bufnr, remap = false}

  vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", function() vim.lsp.buf.definition() end, opts)
  ...
  
  -- *** my new keymap here (does not work) ***
  vim.keymap.set("n", "<C-i>", function() vim.lsp.buf.organize_imports() end, opts)
end)
```

If possible I'd like to stay in the `lsp-zero` ecosystem here, but whatever works is fine. Ideally of course the mapping would only apply in `ts(x)` files.

Comment: If the "organize imports" feature is an LSP extension that's not part of the spec, I doubt it will be available in this way. (For example: I happen to know that ALE has to do some special casing for tsserver-related things, because it has non-LSP features.)

Comment: this thread might be helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/lwz8l7/how_to_use_tsservers_organize_imports_with_nvim/